# Get AWS RDS Aurora cluster endpoint using Ansible

Tags: ansible, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I need to be able to get the [cluster endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html#Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.Types) for an existing AWS RDS Aurora cluster using Ansible by providing the "DB identifier" of the cluster.

When using [community.aws.rds_instance_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/rds_instance_info_module.html) in my playbook and referencing the DB instance identifier of the writer instance:

```
---

- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Get RDS Aurora cluster
      community.aws.rds_instance_info:
        db_instance_identifier: "test-cluster-1" # the writer instance of the aurora db cluster
      register: rds_aurora_cluster
```

It returns that instance as expected.

But if I use the cluster endpoint (`test-cluster`) it does not return any instances, or any cluster-level information:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "instances": [],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aws_access_key": "<omitted>",
            "aws_ca_bundle": null,
            "aws_config": null,
            "aws_secret_key": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "db_instance_identifier": "test-cluster",
            "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false,
            "ec2_url": null,
            "filters": null,
            "profile": null,
            "region": "us-east-1",
            "security_token": null,
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried using the `amazon.aws.aws_rds` module in the [amazon.aws.rds collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_rds_inventory.html), which has an `include_clusters` parameter:

```
---

- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
  collections:
    - amazon.aws
  tasks:
    - name: Get RDS Aurora cluster
      aws_rds:
        db_instance_identifier: "test-cluster"
        include_clusters: true
      register: rds_aurora_cluster
```

When I run that playbook I get:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'aws_rds'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
The error appears to be in '/Users/username/Desktop/test/test.yml': line 23, column 7, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
    - name: Get RDS Aurora cluster
      ^ here
```

I've confirmed that the latest version of the collection is installed:

```
❯ ansible-galaxy collection list
# /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/4.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections
Collection                    Version
----------------------------- -------
amazon.aws                    2.0.0
```

And I have verified the package:

```
❯ ansible-galaxy collection verify amazon.aws
Downloading https://galaxy.ansible.com/download/amazon-aws-2.0.0.tar.gz to /Users/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-8367rrxw073b/tmpejakna6g/amazon-aws-2.0.0-_y4d1bqj
Verifying 'amazon.aws:2.0.0'.
Installed collection found at '/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/4.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/amazon/aws'
MANIFEST.json hash: 1286503f7bcc6dd26aecf9bec4d055e8f0d2e355522f97b620522a5aa754cb9e
Successfully verified that checksums for 'amazon.aws:2.0.0' match the remote collection.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've also tried using the `amazon.aws.aws_rds` module in the amazon.aws.rds collection, which has an `include_clusters` parameter:

One will observe from the documentation you linked to that the `aws_rds` is an *inventory plugin* and not a *module*; it's unfortunate that they have a copy-paste error at the top alleging that one can use it in a playbook, but [the examples section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_rds_inventory.html#examples) shows the correct usage by putting that yaml in a file named `WHATEVER.aws_rds.yaml` and then confirming the selection by running `ansible-inventory -i ./WHATEVER.aws_rds.yaml --list`

Based solely upon some use of `grep -r`, it seems that inventory plugin or [`command: aws rds describe-db-clusters ...`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-clusters.html) are the only two provided mechanisms that are aurora-aware

---

**Working example:**

`test.aws_rds.yml` inventory file:

```yaml
plugin: aws_rds
regions:
  - us-east-1
include_clusters: true
```

`test.yml` playbook, executed with `ansible-playbook test.yml -i ./test.aws_rds.yml`:

```yaml
---

- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: test
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: echo {{ hostvars['test-cluster'].endpoint }}
```